# Css fix - chart items in a div improper alignment

Tags: html, css

Code here - http://jsfiddle.net/Cd2Ek/

html -

```
<div id="main-div" style="height: 250px; margin-left: 10px;">

    <div class="sub-div">
       <div class="">0%</div> <div class="d1" val="0" style="height: 0%"></div>
    <div class=""><small>L1</small></div>
    </div>


    <div class="sub-div">
       <div class="">0%</div> <div class="d1" val="0" style="height: 0%"></div>
    <div class=""><small></small></div>
    </div>


    <div class="sub-div">
       <div class="">33%</div> <div class="d1" val="1" style="height: 33%"></div>
    <div class=""><small>L3</small></div>
    </div>


    <div class="sub-div">
       <div class="">0%</div> <div class="d1" val="0" style="height: 0%"></div>
    <div class=""><small></small></div>
    </div>


    <div class="sub-div">
       <div>67%</div> <div class="d1" val="2" style="height: 67%"></div>
    <div class=""><small>L5</small></div>
    </div>


</div>
```

If you see the output in jsfiddle, the bars are going below the main-div. I think you can guess the actual requirement, all bars should be position from bottom, and if the % is 50, then frm bottom, bar should be upto 50% height of the main div, along with label, % indication.

Comment: Are you trying for some visualization?

Comment: Just a quick tip: using `height: 100%` on one of those bars will make it taller than the height of the main div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need - [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd2Ek/6/). I've rearranged your code quite a lot to simplify how it works, but basically it uses absolute positioning to get the bars to stick to the bottom. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Each bar now uses the HTML:

```
<div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar" style="height:50%">
        <span class="percentage">50%</span>
        <span class="label">L1</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your css with below one

```
  .sub-div {
    margin-right: 6%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid green;
        **vertical-align:top;**
    }
```

Try above code...

Comment: If you see, pink bar is not aligned properly, the bottom should have label(like 10px), pink above it and % at the top(again 10px)

Comment: I didn't understand your problem?? Will you please explain in little details... I am confused with your previous comment. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

CSS

You missed aligning the bars add this line in you `.sub-div` css class

```
vertical-align: top;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd2Ek/2/)